# jquery: Widget not displaying in next click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have following jQuery widget code:

```
(function($){
    var _this,ele;
    $.widget('test.talkWidget',{
        options:{

        },
        destroy: function()
        {            
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },        
        _createTalkBox:function(){
            ele.find(".talk").prepend("<div>Hello</div>");
        },
        _create:function(){this.destroy();
            ele=this.element;
            _this=this;
            var p=$("<div/>").addClass("talk");
            ele.html(p);
            this._createTalkBox();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I am calling it as below inside a click event:

```
$("#somediv").talkWidget();
```

The problem is in first click it create the above discussion widget but in next click it doesn't show the widget. Why?

[See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ga7V/)

Comment: Please create a fiddle so we can see it running.

Comment: I added that.Check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a plugin development expert, but you can change the event handled the `_create` is called once, so you can use the `_init`

[**_init:**](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_init)

> Widgets have the concept of initialization that is distinct from
>   creation. Any time the plugin is called with no arguments or with only
>   an option hash, the widget is initialized; this includes when the
>   widget is created.

Code:

```
(function ($) {
    var _this, ele;
    $.widget('test.talkWidget', {
        options: {

        },
        destroy: function () {
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },
        _createTalkBox: function () {
            ele.find(".talk").prepend("<div>Hello</div>");
        },
        _init: function () {
            this.destroy();
            ele = this.element;
            _this = this;
            var p = $("<div/>").addClass("talk");
            ele.html(p);
            this._createTalkBox();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RPs3S/